# How can I download information from a website if it returns XML/JSON in its response?

Tags: python, screen-scraping

Does Python3 have a built in method to do this? Any guidance at all would be great! :)

The website in question exposes all of its information and even gives you an API key to use.

Comment: I see you've posted this question twice in the last few minutes. You may wish to delete your previous one that does not yet have answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792600/how-can-i-get-download-xml-responde-from-a-website-that-has-a-public-api-using-py

Comment: Woops, thought that question didn't get posted. Already marked it for deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python includes a [`json`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/json.html) module that can do the conversion for you. For downloading the actual data from the web site, use [`urllib.request`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html).